# Display 2D array of characters

Tags: c

I have a small problem with strings in C.
i want to declare 2D character array and to initialize it with 2 variables like this:

```
typedef char tab[4];
tab str[2];
char st, nd;
str[0] = {st,nd,nd,nd,st};
str[1] = {nd,st,st,st,nd};
```

my aim is to declare it like this to be able to initialize as i want, but my problem when i want to display it:

```
for(i = 0;i < 2;i++)
    for(j = 0;j < 4;j++)
        printf("%c", str[i][j]);
```

but it doesn't work!, i don't know where is the problem

Comment: `st` and `nd` are not initialized to anything. What is it you want to print? Also, you cannot use assignment expression to initialize an array object. You can initialize `str[]` itself at its declaration.

Answer (score 2):

```
char st, nd;
str[0] = {st,nd,nd,nd,st};
str[1] = {nd,st,st,st,nd};
```

You never initialize `st` or `nd`, so their value is undefined.  Therefore, you initialize your array with undefined values, which might not represent printable characters.

Further, you are overrunning one of the dimensions of your array.  You have defined it to have four elements, but are initializing it with five.

At this point, the behavior of your program is not defined and it could crash, it could output junk, or it could do nothing at all.  To remedy this:

1. Initialize `st` and `nd` before you use them.
2. Don't write more than four elements to the second dimension of `str`.

(And turn on compiler warnings!  It probably would have warned about both of these problems.)

Comment: I'm guessing that the overrun stems from confusion about the difference between sizes and zero-based indices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you defined the array as having 4 elements in each "row" but are trying to initialize it with 5 initializers.

```
typedef char tab[4];
//...
str[0] = {st,nd,nd,nd,st};
```

Arrays 1) has no assignment operators and 2) {st,nd,nd,nd,st} is not an expression.
Also neither st nor nd were initialized.

You could initialize the array when you declared it. If you need to change its values after its definition then you have to do this manually.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   5

int main(void) 
{
    typedef char tab[N];
    char st = 'A', nd = 'B';
    tab str[2] = 
    {
        { st, nd, nd, nd, st },
        { nd, st, st, st, nd }
    };
    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%c", str[i][j] );
        puts( "" );
    }

    puts( "" );

    st = 'B';
    nd = 'A';

    memset( str[0], nd, N );
    str[0][0] = str[0][N-1] = st;

    memset( str[1], st, N );
    str[1][0] = str[1][N-1] = nd;

    for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%c", str[i][j] );
        puts( "" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
ABBBA
BAAAB

BAAAB
ABBBA
```